# Does a custom destructor necessitate custom copy and move operations?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, destructor

I am currently reading [The C++ Programming Language, Strousrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840). I know it's a popular book, so I believe that referencing the section numbers will help. At the end of `section 17.6 Generating Default operations`, in the last bullet point he says:

> If the programmer declares a copy operation, a move operation, or a destructor for a class, no copy operation, move operation, or destructor is generated for that class

Later on, from my understanding, he clarifies that statement to mean that if *either* a copy or move operation (i.e. via assignment or CTOR) or destructor are provided by the programmer, the compiler will not provide defaults for the other two (2). He does this in `section 17.6.3.3 Resource Invariants`. First, he offers the following class, in `section 17.6.3.3 Resource Invariants`:

```
template <typename T>
class Handle {
    T* p;
    public:
    Handle (T* pp): p{pp} {}
    T& operator*() {return *p;}
    ~Handle() {delete p;}
};
```

and then states:

> `Handle` declares a destructor: this suppresses the generation of copy and move operations. Again, this saves us from a nasty problem. Consider:

```
void f3()
{
    Handle<int> h1 {new int{7}};
    Handle<int> h2 {h1};            // error: no copy constructor
}
```

He goes onto to mention, that:

> Caveat: the generation of copy operations is only deprecated, not banned, so if you ignore warnings, you might get this example past the compiler

#### PROBLEM:

I have reproduced this code, verbatim, and I am able to compile it without any warnings (`g++ sec17_6_3_3.cpp -Wall -std=c++11`). Then, after I run the compiled code, as expected, I receive:

```
sec17_6_3_3(6451,0x11717be00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd3ed4059f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I have reviewed the *rule of three* and the [*rule of five*](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html), but I suppose I am not fully understanding if these *rules* are compiler rules or strongly recommended programming practices.

What am I missing?

Comment: [The rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) If the book really says this, then it's either incorrect or perhaps obsolete. A copy constructor is indeed implicitly defined for `Handle`. The problem is, that copy constructor isn't doing the right thing - it just copies over the pointer, leaving two instances of `Handle` both thinking they own the same pointer, eventually leading to double destructrion.

Comment: Rule of Five is indeed only a strongly recommended programming practice. I don't know of any compiler that would warn about violations of this rule, so it's up to programmer to keep to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - so why does Stroustrup say that it should not compile, and if it does, then it should issue warnings?

Comment: The code should compile. I don't know why Stroustrup says otherwise, if indeed he does. As to warnings - that's a quality-of-implementation issue. A sufficiently smart compiler could perhaps detect and warn about an unsafe pattern. I don't think mainstream compilers are that smart; static code analyzers might be.

Comment: Clarification: it is indeed true that providing a user-defined copy constructor suppresses an implicitly declared move constructor, and providing a user-defined move constructor makes copy constructor implicitly defined as deleted. However, the presence of a user-defined destructor doesn't affect either constructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I put his quote in my post. I suppose then, that this is *completely* dependent upon programmer discretion and that the compiler *will* compile and will also probably not throw any warnings. What's interesting is that, in that section,  he uses this technique (I.e. providing a DTOR wo/ copy or move operations) as a design approach for protection against dangling pointers.

Comment: He states right after ``f3()``: **"Had ``Handle`` had a default copy constructor, both ``h1`` and ``h2`` would have had a copy of the pointer and both would have ``delete``d it"**. Well, this is *exactly* what the compiler let me do. So, I guess the issue isn't so much whether a person *should* do something like this, but rather, can a person allow the compiler to handle this for you. It appears, contrary to Stroustrup, no. Sounds crazy to say.

Comment: I take it back. The C++ standard does indeed talk about [deprecating this case](https://eel.is/c++draft/depr.impldec). Far as I can tell, this language has been in the standard for 10 years, since C++11. I suspect it's roundly ignored by typical compilers as too much existing code would break otherwise. Even with `-Wall` and `--pedantic`, neither clang nor gcc complain.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - yeah, so I compiled with ``-std=c++11`` since that's what this book is based upon, with ``-Wall``.  ``-Wpedantic`` did not change anything.

Comment: You get no warnings because this class of warnings is much contested (e.g https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88136) and so typically isn't in `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

As `@Unslander Monica` pointed out, this class of warning [is draconian and shouldn't be in -Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88136).
When compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wdeprecated  mainapp.cpp -o mainApp
```

I do, indeed, receive the warning that Stroustrup referred to:

```
warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'Handle<int>' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor [-Wdeprecated]
```